# UITableViewCell is displayed incorrectly the first time

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I'm toggling between different cell backgrounds (white and lightgray) and font properties (bold and normal) with the following code after cell creation or reuse:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
    cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {
...

 UIView* cellBackgroundView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
 UIFont *font;
 if ([[userModel suspended] boolValue]) {
   [cellBackgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
   font = [UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:[[[cell textLabel] font] pointSize]];

 } else {
   [cellBackgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
   font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:[[[cell textLabel] font] pointSize]];
 }
 [cell setBackgroundView:cellBackgroundView];  
 [[cell textLabel] setFont:font];

 [[cell textLabel] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
 [[cell detailTextLabel] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
 [[cell textLabel] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", 
                            [userModel familyName], [userModel givenName]]];
 [[cell detailTextLabel] setText:[userModel userName]];

return cell;
}
```

The problem is that if a cell that needs to be **lightgray** and **italic** is on the first set of cells displayed after loading, its background appears **lightgray** (correctly) but its font is **normal** (wrong).

If I scroll down and have the cell redisplayed, then it displays as expected.

Thanks,
Jorge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line

```
font = [UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:[[[cell textLabel] font] pointSize]]
```

you are assuming that the cell textLabel already exists and has a correct font.  I would NSLog the font just before that call.  Also why not just specify the fontsize here:
    font = [UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:12.0]

Comment: You are correct. Solved the issue.

The problem at that point the font size is returned as 0.
    <GSFont 0x5957130>{size = 0.000000, traits = 00000001}

Setting the text before executing that line has the same effect.

    font = [UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:[[[cell textLabel] font] pointSize]]

It seems that the font properties for the cell are configured at some point afterwards.

Comment: I wasted two hours trying everything before I found this page... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is there a chance that the boolean returned by [[userModel suspended] boolValue] is false at the time when the first group of cells are created?

Comment: No, I checked with a breakpoint and it's executed when the first set of cells is created.